# mod_rewrite behaving strangely when . (dot) in regex

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am trying to redirect all traffic to my site to a single script as such:

```
example.com/fictitious/path/to/resource
```

should become

```
example.com/target.php?path=fictitious/path/to/resource
```

and I have set up my .htaccess file as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase "/"
RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "target.php?path=$1"
```

target.php looks like this for testing purposes:

```
<?php echo $_GET["path"] ?>
```

However, when I go to "example.com/path/to/resource" target.php just echoes "target.php" instead of "path/to/resource". When I change my .htaccess as such

```
[...]
RewriteRule "^([a-zA-Z\/]*)$" "target.php?path=$1"
```

Surely enough, target.php faithfully echoes "path/to/resource", but as soon as I add an ESCAPED dot to my rule as such:

```
[...]
RewriteRule "^([a-zA-Z\/\.]*)$" "target.php?path=$1"
```

target.php echoes "target.php" again.

What is going on? Why is the dot in my regex messing with my capture group's contents in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that your rule is looping and thus running twice. After first execution `REQUEST_URI` becomes `target.php` and in 2nd execution, you get same in `path` parameter.

It is because you don't have any condition to avoid running this rule for existing files and directories.

You may use:

```
RewriteEngine on

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ target.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you! so am I right in assuming that it takes the URL from the user request, rewrites it, and then starts the chain for the rewritten URL from the top, until the URL does not change anymore? Because my previous assumption was that it just runs through the chain once, rewriting just the request URL.

Comment: Yes exactly, Your assumption is correct that it starts from the top again. See this for more details: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html